# What are the coordinates of red point?

Tags: calculus

> The function  $f (x)=-x^2+4$ "in red" is moving along the line $y=x+4$  " in black "  from green point  to  black point  and becomes in the place of blue graph  as shown in the following  graph

[image]

What are the coordinates  of red point?

I got the green point $(0,4)$ by using the equation  $y=x+4$ ,  and got the intersection  point of the two  parabolas $(2,0)$  and I stopped here.

Comment: From the diagram one can see that the point is $(8,0)$.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen  i am sorry  for making  misunderstanding about the post , i edited  the post ; hope that will reflect my intention

Comment: Now that all of that is out of the way, what are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @amd  i got the green point $(0,4)$ by using the equation  $y=x+4$ ,  and got the intersection  point of the two  parabolas $(2,0)$  ; and i stopped here

Comment: If we call the unknown $x$-coordinate of the black point $x_c$, what would be the equation of the blue parabola?

Comment: Is [tag:calculus] really the best tag for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can solve this problem by remembering function transformations.

The equation of the original parabola is $y = -x^2 + 4$. You are shifting the parabola along a line of slope $1$, which means that the parabola is shifting up the same ammount as it is shifting to the right. So the equation of the blue parabola will be $y = -(x-h)^2 + 4+h$, where $h$ is a positive constant.

Since the blue parabola and the red parabola share an $x$ intercept, we know that $(2, 0)$ satisfies $y = -(x-h)^2 + 4 + h$. If we plug in $(2, 0)$, we can solve for $h$, and then we are done. Can you do the rest?

Comment: thank you for help;  i got $h=5$  so the vertex  is $(5,9)$ , right?

Comment: @prayersmith Yes you are correct!

Comment: and so the red point will be $(8,0)$    ; Elegant  Solution and reasoning;  thank you very much

Comment: @prayersmith Correct! You're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

If you slide the green point some distance $d$ to the right along the line, then both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point increase by $d$. This means that the shifted parabola has the equation $(y-d)=4-(x-d)^2$. You know that this shifted parabola passes through the intersection point $(2,0)$, so plug that in and solve for $d$, then find the other $x$-intercept of the resulting equation (you can use symmetry to make that last step really easy).

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are good but here's another way to do it. Given a parabola with it's vertex on the line $y=x+4$ and $a=-1$, and a zero at $x=2$, the height of the parabola will be $x+4$, and $x$-distance from the vertex to the zero will be $|x-2|$. Thus, $(x+4)-|x-2|^2 = 0$, or $x^2-5x = 0$, which means that $x=0$ (the red parabola), or $x=5$ (the blue parabola). Since the distance from the vertex to each of it's roots are the same, we calculate $|x-2|$, and we can add and subtract that to $x$, the $x$-coordinate of the vertex. This gives us the two zeros of the blue parabola.